# Mongodb find in array and select that index

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a Document setup like this:

Users

```
{
 _id : '',
 name : '',
 friends : [
   {
     'name' : '',
     'email' : '',
     'age' : ''
   }
 ]
}
```

I'm trying to select a single friend from within the friends array by email, while only returning that specific object.

Any suggestions how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db.mytest.find({'friends.email':'abhi2'},{friends : {$elemMatch : {email : 'abhi2'}}}).pretty() 
Or
db.mytest.find({'_id':'a'},{friends : {$elemMatch : {name : 'abhi2'}}}).pretty()
```

For more details, look this doc : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/projection/elemMatch/